# Check ownership of a token in another chain

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, cross-chain

I know how to check ownership of a token which relies on the same chain, but I need to check ownership of a token which is in another EVM chain.

For exemple, NFT contract is deployed on **Polygon** (I can have full code, ABI, contract address etc...). Then I want to deploy another contract on **Ethereum** which will check ownership of the NFTs on **Polygon** and act accordingly.

Is there any way to check this within the contract? If not, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The workarounds would be:

1. *(Proactive)* using [Chainlinks GET](https://docs.chain.link/docs/any-api/get-request/introduction/) requests - you can make requests to your backend, which then returns the owner for the asset.
2. *(Passiv)* Provide the ownership information as a transaction argument.

   - Before the user submits a transaction to the Ethereum chain, your backend checks the ownership for some asset on Polygon
   - Your backend signs this data with your aka Validator Private Key. You can include additional data, like the current block number, or current block timestamp (*Those could be like a nonce value, to prevent reentrancy*).
   - Then you create a transaction for the user, add those values with the signature as the arguments,
   - User submits the transaction
   - In the polygons contract, you recover the signature to check if it was signed by your validator address, and act accordingly.

*I would prefer the second option*